# having jquery enabled prevents post deletion?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

in my application.html, i have this inside:

```
 ...
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 ...
```

in my _post.html, i have the follow block to allow users to delete posts:

```
<% if current_user == post.user or can? :manage, :all %>
     <span class ="plaintext"> [<%= link_to_if(can?(:delete, post), 'Delete', post_path(post), :class=>'delbuttons', :id=>'delete', :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete) {} %>]
     </span>
    <% end %>
```

for some reason, though, having the  line prevents my posts from being deleted! it's very weird. how do i enable deletion again? i'm on Rails 3.

Comment: Are you on rails 3 or rails 3.1? Why are you using old jquery?

Comment: i'm currently on rails 3 -- how exactly would i go about updating the jquery? thanks in advance

Comment: Here's the url for the latest jQuery library: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As most browsers don't natively support the delete HTTP verb, rails uses javascript to be able to perform a delete action. To have this working with jquery you'll need to include a version of rails.js that works with jQuery (and the version of jQuery you are using).

You can get the latest copy of jQuery here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
 And grab the latest rails.js here: https://raw.github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/master/src/rails.js

Update your application layout to include both like so:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.7.1.min.js' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'rails.js' %>
```